# Why setting void pointer to an address of int pointer in c is ok and the reverse is not?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have:

```
void *abc;
int *abc2;

int someInt = 5;
int *intPtr = &someInt;
abc = intPtr;   // This line is ok without casting
abc2 = abc;     // Here will be an error without casting
```

Why is this?

Comment: [No error for me](http://ideone.com/gm9xYy), are you compiling the code as C++? Believe it or not, C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: Can you provide your compiler output as well (ie: `gcc myFile.c -Wall`)? This will help.

Answer (score 2):

In C language both assignments (both lines) are perfectly OK without casting.

The second line would produce an error in C++, but your question is tagged C. Your assertion about an error on the second line is false.